# Can't boot directly to ubuntu

Tags: 14.04

I was using windows 8.1, when I installed ubuntu I chose to erase and install. Now when I boot, I am given the windows 8 recovery screen. The only way I can boot to ububtu is by going to the boot menu and selecting the hard disk, and yes I have two internal hard disks, but the other never had any os installed in it. And the options in the windows recovery screen dont function, when I press any given key ( f8,9,...) the screen just blinks and nothing happens, I have to press restart button and boot via boot menu.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you installed ubuntu to the second internal hard drive. You need to change the hard drive priority in your BIOS under Boot, so that the second hard drive is the primary boot drive.

Comment: It is, and no, all my os installs are in one hdd only

Comment: Be that as it may, ubuntu still must have created the boot partition on your other hard drive. Otherwise manually selecting that hard drive wouldn't work.